# How to get the previous event for each row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, in-app-purchase

I'm gathering events data from different data sources and merging them on a pandas dataframe.

I have two different event types (clicks and purchases) and I want to replicate a "last click attribution model".
This consists of finding which was the last click the user did, previous to make a purchase.

In other words, I have think of it as follows:
"for each purchase event, get the last click event previous to that purchase (if any)"

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'user_id': [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234],
   'event_type': ['CLICK','CLICK','PURCHASE','PURCHASE','CLICK','PURCHASE','CLICK','CLICK'],
    'event_id': [4567, 7891, 11215, 14539, 17863, 21187, 24511, 27835],
   'timestamp': [2, 4, 7, 7, 14, 134, 739, 921]
    } );
```

```
   user_id event_type  event_id  timestamp
0     1234      CLICK      4567          2
1     1234      CLICK      7891          4
2     1234   PURCHASE     11215          7
3     1234   PURCHASE     14539          7
4     1234      CLICK     17863         14
5     1234   PURCHASE     21187        134
6     1234      CLICK     24511        739
7     1234      CLICK     27835        921
```

I have tried the following:

1. Sorting values by user_id and timestamp
2. Adding columns "previous_event_type", "previous event timestamp" with .shift().
3. Adding conditional to evaluate if event_type and previous_event_type is "CLICK AND PURCHASE"

```
df['previous_event_type'] = df['event_type'].shift()
df['previous_event_timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].shift()
df['click_to_purchase'] = (df['event_type'] == 'PURCHASE') & (df['previous_event_type'] == 'CLICK')
```

Main problem with this solution is:
if the user did two or more purchases, I can't get the last click previous to the second purchase (and I should)

Is there a way you can think of creating a function to:
***"for each purchase event, get the last click event previous to that purchase (if any)"***

Can't think of other way to describe it.

[Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGRUX.png)

Thanks,
Javier.

Comment: share a desired output from the df your provided it will give us a better view on your question (what result would you expect to see)

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply adhg. I'm adding a screenshot of what comes to my mind.

Comment: what is the timestamp col? you can just do a `groupby` with an `agg` function and pass `last` as your argument.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can avoid `groupby`, using some masking, with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), as well as `ffill` (being equivalent to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the method 'ffill'). To see that it is not considering last `CLICK` when new user, I added a new line to your dataframe with a new user and `PURCHASE` with `df.loc[8,:] = [1235, 'PURCHASE', 11, 4]`

```
#first sort_values
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'timestamp'])

#create the mask of click
mask_click = df.event_type.eq('CLICK')

#create the mask of user, what you want is the last click if the same user
mask_user = df.user_id.where(mask_click).ffill() != df.user_id

#now create the columns
df['last_click_id'] = df.event_id.where(mask_click).ffill().mask( mask_click | mask_user)
df['last_click_timestamp'] = df.timestamp.where(mask_click).ffill().mask( mask_click | mask_user)

print (df)
   user_id event_type  event_id  timestamp  last_click_id  \
0   1234.0      CLICK    4567.0        2.0            NaN   
1   1234.0      CLICK    7891.0        4.0            NaN   
2   1234.0   PURCHASE   11215.0        7.0         7891.0   
3   1234.0   PURCHASE   14539.0        7.0         7891.0   
4   1234.0      CLICK   17863.0       14.0            NaN   
5   1234.0   PURCHASE   21187.0      134.0        17863.0   
6   1234.0      CLICK   24511.0      739.0            NaN   
7   1234.0      CLICK   27835.0      921.0            NaN   
8   1235.0   PURCHASE      11.0        4.0            NaN   #still nan as new user while purchase

   last_click_timestamp  
0                   NaN  
1                   NaN  
2                   4.0  
3                   4.0  
4                   NaN  
5                  14.0  
6                   NaN  
7                   NaN  
8                   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do a mask to find which consecutive rows have click followed by purchase, then assign the last columns with shift, and finally forward fill where there is a consecutive purchase

```
m = df['event_type'].eq('PURCHASE') & df['event_type'].shift().eq('CLICK')
df.loc[m, 'last click'] = df['event_id'].shift()
df.loc[m, 'last time'] = df['timestamp'].shift()
df.loc[df['event_type'].eq('PURCHASE')]= df.loc[df['event_type'].eq('PURCHASE')].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you would like to do that on a per-user basis.

First, since order is important, sort the dataframe by `user_id` and `timestamp`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['user_id', 'timestamp']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

For each users, split `PURCHASE` and `CLICK` into 2 separate dataframes and slice the `clicks` dataframe different per purchase:

```
def summarize(x):
    purchases = x[x['event_type'] == 'PURCHASE']
    clicks = x[x['event_type'] == 'CLICK']
    last_clicks = purchases.index.to_series().apply(lambda i: clicks.loc[:i].iloc[-1]) 
    return purchases.join(last_clicks[['event_type', 'event_id', 'timestamp']].add_prefix('last_'))

df.groupby('user_id').apply(summarize) \
    .droplevel(1).drop(columns='user_id')   # drop extra columns
```

Result:

```
        event_type  event_id  timestamp last_event_type  last_event_id  last_timestamp
user_id                                                                               
1234      PURCHASE     11215          7           CLICK           7891               4
1234      PURCHASE     14539          7           CLICK           7891               4
1234      PURCHASE     21187        134           CLICK          17863              14
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {
   'user_id': [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234],
   'event_type': ['CLICK','CLICK','PURCHASE','PURCHASE','CLICK','PURCHASE','CLICK','CLICK'],
    'event_id': [4567, 7891, 11215, 14539, 17863, 21187, 24511, 27835],
   'timestamp': [2, 4, 7, 7, 14, 134, 739, 921]
    } )

df = pd.concat([df, df.assign(user_id=1235)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Solution:**

```
df['clk_events'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.iloc[0:x.name].loc[lambda y: (y.event_type=='CLICK') & (y.user_id==x.user_id)], axis=1)
df['last_clk'] = df.clk_events.apply(lambda x: np.nan if len(x)==0 else x.event_id.tolist()[-1])
df.loc[df.event_type=='CLICK', 'last_clk']=np.nan
df.drop('clk_events',1, inplace=True)

user_id event_type  event_id    timestamp   last_clk
0   1234    CLICK       4567    2           NaN
1   1234    CLICK       7891    4           NaN
2   1234    PURCHASE    11215   7           7891.0
3   1234    PURCHASE    14539   7           7891.0
4   1234    CLICK       17863   14          NaN
5   1234    PURCHASE    21187   134         17863.0
6   1234    CLICK       24511   739         NaN
7   1234    CLICK       27835   921         NaN
8   1235    CLICK       4567    2           NaN
9   1235    CLICK       7891    4           NaN
10  1235    PURCHASE    11215   7           7891.0
11  1235    PURCHASE    14539   7           7891.0
12  1235    CLICK       17863   14          NaN
13  1235    PURCHASE    21187   134         17863.0
14  1235    CLICK       24511   739         NaN
15  1235    CLICK       27835   921         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added for only for last_click_id but if you need help with timestamp too let me know.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['time_stamp'])

def f(x):
    index = x['index']
    event = x['event_type']
    if event == "purchase":
        return np.nan if index==0 else df.loc[index-1,'event_id']
    else:
        return df.loc[index,'event_id']

df['last_click_id'] = df[['index','event type']].apply(lambda x:f(x))
```